# multiple indipendent variable for linear regression in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, linear-regression, google-sheets-api

in google sheets i got error when i try to make a linear regression with multiple (2) indipendent variables.

```
A         B       C

field1  field2  field3
33         2    580
33         3    1245
33         4    1156
33         5    3535
33         6    4976
33         7    3050
33         8    5779
```

my code is

=LINEST(C2:C8;A2:B8;1)

and the error is #NUM! --> Result was not a number.

Another error that came out is #N/A --> Cannot perform regression in LINEST due to linearly dependent variables.

what i'm writing wrongly?

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094249?hl=en

Here google sais that *If known_data_y is a one-dimensional array or range, known_data_x may represent multiple independent variables in a two-dimensional array or range* where:

LINEST(known_data_y, [known_data_x], [calculate_b], [verbose])

Comment: I tried your same set up and it worked fine for me. However, the "fields" are text and a number is required. What does the error in #NUM say?

Comment: i don't consider "fields" for the regression. Error says "result was not a number". I checked that there aren't Nan or empty cells.

Comment: Another error is "#N/A" : Cannot perform regression in LINEST due to linearly dependent variables.

Comment: I see. Could you share a copy of the Sheet? Make sure the cells are formatted as numbers. Select all of them and go to Format > Number > Number

Comment: It's strange because i have 190 rows. If i do it for 20 lines, it works well, but if i try it for all the dataset it gives me the #N/A error

Comment: This looks like something related to the logic of the function. If you replace the 1 with 0, then it works for all the ranges, but then it can't predict the third value. Where is this data coming from?